# Remove duplicate rows based on multiple columns using dplyr / tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on >1 column using dplyr / tidyverse

#### Example

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b=c(1,2,1,2,1,2), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I thought this would return rows 3 and 6, but it returns 0 rows.

```
df %>% filter(duplicated(a, b))
# [1] a b
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Conversely, I thought this would return rows 1,2,4 and 5, but it returns all rows.

```
df %>% filter(!duplicated(a, b))
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 1
# 4 2 2
# 5 2 1
# 6 2 2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`duplicated`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) expected to operate on *"a vector or a data frame or an array"* (but not *two vectors* ... it looks for duplication in its first argument only).

```r
df %>%
  filter(duplicated(.))
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2

df %>%
  filter(!duplicated(.))
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 2 2
# 4 2 1
```

If you prefer to reference a specific subset of columns, then use `cbind`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(duplicated(cbind(a, b)))
```

As a side note, the `dplyr` verb for this can be `distinct`:

```r
df %>%
  distinct(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE)
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 2 2
# 4 2 1
```

though I don't know that it has an inverse of this function.

Comment: Very nice. Also, I thought the `cbind` approach would fail in some rare cases like `df <- data.frame(a=c(11, 1), b=c(1,12), stringsAsFactors = F); df %>% filter(duplicated(cbind(a, b)))`, but it doesn't. Looks like a great solution.

Comment: Since your edit, I will use `distinct` since that is the most 'native' tidy approach. Keen to know if there's an inverse to it, just for learning/knowledge

Comment: Maybe `janitor::get_dupes`?

Comment: I haven't had the need for that package.

Comment: Don't ask me why I thought of it now (~2 years later), but cbind(a, b) could cause accidental matches (e.g. `data.frame(a=c("xy", "x"), b=c("x", "yx"))`). So I think `distinct` is the superior choice.. PS congrats on 100k

Comment: I don't see how `cbind(a,b)` can make a mistake with your new sample frame there, since `"xy"` and `"x"` (row 1) are never truly combined. That is, I think you're saying that `"xyx"` might be ambiguous; that is not conveyed, so that error shouldn't happen. Is it behaving incorrectly for you? (Don't congrat me too early, I'm still 6 points shy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Using `unique` on the dataframe gives the unique rows.

```
unique(df)

#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 1 2
#4 2 2
#5 2 1
```

Alternatively, a tidy approach could be to select 1st row of each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% slice(1L) 
#If only 2 columns
#df %>% group_by_all() %>%slice(1L)

#      a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     2     1
#4     2     2
```

The inverse would be :

```
df %>%  group_by(a, b) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>%  distinct()
#If only 2 columns
#df %>%  group_by_all() %>% filter(n() > 1) %>%  distinct()

#     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     2     2
```